# Not able to triger any event on vue-select

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am working on vue-select to input / select from dropdown, so on select of any option I am trying to get the value which is selected

**Code**

```
<vueSelect 
       :clearable="false"
       v-on:change="itemCodeChange($event)"
       :options="itemCode">
</vueSelect>
```

**script**

```
    import vueSelect from 'vue-select'
    import 'vue-select/dist/vue-select.css';
    components :{
        vueSelect,

    },
  data () {
     return {
        itemCode:[],
     }      
  },
   methods:{
  itemCodeChange (a)
      {
          alert(a)
      }
```

When I am changing nothing is happening

Comment: is vueSelect this thing? https://vue-select.org/ - it has [documentation](https://vue-select.org/guide/values.html#getting-and-setting)

Comment: @JaromandaX main thing is change or input is not triggered, I checked that but didn't get it, that's why asked here

Comment: @JaromandaX could you please show me some code accordingly

Comment: change `v-on:change="itemCodeChange($event)"` to `v-on:input="itemCodeChange"` in your code - note the lack of `$event`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the input event not the change event: see working code

```js
Vue.component('v-select', VueSelect.VueSelect)

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    options: [
      'foo',
      'bar',
      'baz'
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    changed(v) { console.log(v); }
  }
})
```

```css
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:600';
@import 'https://unpkg.com/vue-select/dist/vue-select.css';

body {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #2c3e5099;
  text-rendering: optimizelegibility;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -moz-text-size-adjust: none;
}

#app {
  max-width: 30em;
  margin: 1em auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <h1>Vue Select</h1>
  <v-select :options="options" @input="changed"></v-select>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-select@latest"></script>
```